# ACL In Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, acl

In laravel 4.2, I want to do Access Control List (ACL) on my controller. Can I do the controls in `ACLController` which extends from `BaseController`, then `functionController` extends from `ACLController`?

But I have no idea how to start the `functionController`.

Answer (score 1):

You must create a roles table in your database first. Then there will be a table named 'user_roles'. Now you have to see which roles are defined to a particular user.

**Implementation:** Yes you can create an ACL controller that extends  BaseController. Inside its function get user roles and put it inside session for further controls.